# Magento 2 Create account on cart page

Tags: magento2, cart

On the cart page and after Guest checkout if click on create account nothing is happening and just showing below:

[image]

Comment: check magento log files for error, that give you more idea.

Comment: where is it possible to find error about this

Comment: you need to either check magento log files available at Magento Root->var->log or check consol.

Answer (score 0):

Issue found, I'm using Guest to Customer extension and that was causing this error